# How to become a baker - some doubts and questions

Tags: baking, kiln

I have some very important questions.

I'm carefully considering whether to become a Baker on Tezos.

I have noticed that there are many ways and software that I can use, including Kiln, as it runs on Mac and is, as I understand it, an all-in-one software to manage my "Baker" position. In this way I would avoid the whole Linux configuration part (since I'm not a programmer), with the risk of making a mistake, and I would rely on Kiln on Mac mini.

- 1. The first question is whether M2 processors, Apple's new ones, are supported?
- 2. The second question is how the rewards are managed, which I will then
     have to distribute to my delegates: (example: 100 users delegate me
     Tezos, the amount for each person varies from 1 to 100 Tezos. After
     cooking a few blocks, how do I distribute the rewards, based on the
     amount that has been allocated to me, to the 100 people? Does all the
     Klin software automatically?)

Comment: It's best to post one question per post. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post

Comment: I edited the question and will post next question when this is answered. Thank you